# No active mode when HDMI reconnects, when TV switched on again

Tags: graphics, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

I've recent upgraded the tiny Ubuntu Linux box under my TV, to a Zotac ZBox. The graphics on it are provided by, according to `lspci`, Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21).

It's connected to my TV over HDMI. It's working almost perfectly! When I power the machine up, all is good. The problem comes when I switch the TV off, then back on again.

While the TV is off, `xrandr` correctly detects everything is disconnected as I'd expect:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I switch the TV on, the TV (in HDMI mode) just sits there saying "No Signal" and "Connecting". If I run xrandr in this state, it knows the TV is back, and knows what modes it supports, but is missing the all-important `*` of an active mode:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00   29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1024     60.02
   1360x768      59.80
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x576i      50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

Running `xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto` causes it to pick a mode, and the TV springs into life showing the computer once more! The output of xrandr now has that key `*` against the active mode:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1024     60.02
   1360x768      59.80
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x576i      50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

While it isn't the end of the world to turn on the TV, wake up another computer, ssh in, and run `DISPLAY=:0.0 xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto` before doing anything else, it certainly isn't an ideal user experience...

What settings do I need to tweak so that, when the HDMI connection comes back, X picks a mode, rather than the current behaviour?